# boost::asio::steady_timer stops firing

Tags: c++, timer, boost-asio

I wrote the following little test driver program to test some mouse events in another windows application.

For some reason, it stops firing around the 5th or 6th time it triggers. If I put a break point in the callback and resume when it is hit, it works fine.

It is giving me no exceptions or failure codes. I just see two thread exit in the visual studio output window.

What am I missing?

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include "boost/asio/deadline_timer.hpp"
#include<boost/bind.hpp>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

class Pooper
{
    boost::asio::io_context & m_ioContext;
    boost::asio::steady_timer m_timer;

public:
    Pooper(boost::asio::io_context & ioContext)
        :
        m_ioContext(ioContext)
        , m_timer(boost::asio::steady_timer(ioContext))
    {
    }

    void Run()
    {
        m_timer.expires_from_now(std::chrono::seconds(5));
        m_timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&Pooper::OnTimerExpired, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }

    void OnTimerExpired(const boost::system::error_code & error)
    {
        if (error.failed())
        {
            std::cerr << "boost error: Failed" << std::endl;
        }

        std::cout << "Poop" << std::endl;

        try
        {
            // Move the mouse
            int x = 500;
            int y = 500;
            if (!::SetCursorPos(x, y))
            {
                int errorCode = GetLastError();
                std::cerr << "SetCursorPos error: " << errorCode << std::endl;
            }

            // Left button down
            x = 65536 * 500;
            y = 65536 * 500;
            ::mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, x, y, NULL, NULL);

            // Left button up
            x = 65536 * 500;
            y = 65536 * 500;
            ::mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, x, y, NULL, NULL);

            m_timer.expires_from_now(std::chrono::seconds(5));
            m_timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&Pooper::OnTimerExpired, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
        }
        catch (std::exception &)
        {
            std::cerr << "An exception occured." << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_context ioContext;
    auto pooper = Pooper(ioContext);
    pooper.Run();
    ioContext.run();

    std::cerr << "Exited..." << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Your problem is elsewhere - this [code is ok](https://wandbox.org/permlink/I7oXwqNaEu17Jyoe), not accounting for any MSVC/Win32 weirdness. What version of Boost/MSVC are you on?

Comment: This was on the latest version of boost. 1.70.0 installed from "boost_1_70_0-unsupported-msvc-14.2-64.exe", Running on windows 10, using Visual Studio 2019. There is nowhere else for the problem to be. I posted exactly what I am running. I will try the one for vc140 in a minute to see if any change.